# php json encode not working properly

Tags: javascript, php

im having hard time looking what's wrong with my code. im using json encode to pass php value to javascript.

this is the javascript code
the code below works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function functiondecline() { 
        var signatoryidglobal = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['signatoryid']); ?>
        alert(signatoryidglobal);
    }
</script>
```

but if i read the value of another session it will not work. why? even alert will not pop up. i even checked if the session has a value by using this code

```
echo $_SESSION['Login_id'];
```

and it has value in it.

i even put the javascript code at the button but it doesnt work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function functiondecline() { 
        var signatoryidglobal = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['signatoryid']); ?>
        var login_id = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['signatoryid']); ?>
        alert(signatoryidglobal);
        alert(login_id);
    }
</script>
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you show the output JavaScript for both with and without reading the value of another session?

Comment: First of all, check the browser console for errors! Second you need to wrap the result of `json_encode()` in quotes. Third have you called the function? If so, how are you calling the function `functiondecline`?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois json_encode returns valid javascript based on the variable passed to it. You do NOT need to wrap it in quotes single, double, utf-8, latin, ascii, or otherwise. Stop posting misinformation...

Comment: @JosephYoung the output sir is just a text from database. i created those session in the login page. why is it not working sir? im pretty sure that the session has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes around the json_encode function, not the whole php block:

```
var signatoryidglobal = <?= "'".json_encode($_SESSION['signatoryid'])."';"; ?>
```

Comment: it doesnt work sir. i dont know why. i even checked the value of session

Answer (score -1):

variable format invalid!
correct is:

```
var test = 'string';
```

this:

```
var signatoryidglobal = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['signatoryid']); ?>
var login_id = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['signatoryid']); ?>
```

change for:

```
var signatoryidglobal = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["signatoryid"]); ?>';
var login_id = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["signatoryid"]); ?>';
```

Comment: This will result in improper syntax.

Take for instance a string: `$var = "testing"`;

When you `json_encode` that you get exactly: `"testing"`, now if you add double quotes around that you will end up with: `""testing""` which is invalid syntax in javascript.

Comment: no! json_encode return {"test":"test"}, for javascript working need '{"test":"test"}'; . with ;

Comment: ha ok dude, that will make it a string and unusable via JS. You would then have re-parse it as JSON... seems kind of silly to pass in an object as a string. 

Additionally if you do that, I suggest you try to write a JS line of code like this: 

var json = "{"test":"test"}";

Does it work? lol

Comment: I really had posted with a typo, but it's no reason to be negative to tip, just let in a comment that I would fix.

Comment: Yea sorry for the negativity, but the problem is that this doesn't solve the issue at hand, in fact this will ultimately cause more issues. It will just result in a string, even if the variable to be encoded is an object. Again `json_encode` handles everything for you already. Your proposed solution will result in unnecessary characters for strings and objects will be string representations of themselves and not usable without further manipulation. ie. `$var = 'string'` will become a js variable with an explicit value of: `"string"` (including the quotes)

Comment: You are incorrect... Then why does this work for me without `JSON.parse()` ?   `<script type="text/javascript">var data = <?php echo isset($this->data) ? json_encode($this->data) : '{"migration" : {}}'; ?></script>` Am I a magician?